# Spring and serialization to Json - how to customize globally Jackson without Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm using clean Spring MVC framework (v5.3.21) without Spring Boot.
I was working with Gson library, which was used by Spring to serialize view models, returned with request methods.

```
 public class Coffee {
    String name = "n";
    String brand = "b";
 }
    
 @RequestMapping(value={"/coffe"}, method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public Coffee getCoffee() {
    return new Coffee();
 }
```

Recently I added Jackson (v 2.13.3) on the classpath and I've noticed serialization works much different. First of all - in Gson non-private field where serialized by default, now they are not visible at the client side.
I know I can add annotation

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.NON_PRIVATE)
```

to all the model classes, or change fields to public (Jackson default visibility for fields is PUBLIC, as far as I found out).
But I would like to change just once, globally, in configuration, without rewriting code of many

I tried many options, but none of them doesn't work without Spring Boot.
Do you know to change this default setting with clean Spring?

Answer (score 0):

You can create `ObjectMapper` bean which can be global for application

```
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {

    ObjectMapper mapper  = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setVisibility(mapper.getSerializationConfig().getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
            .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NON_PRIVATE));

    return mapper;
 }
```

Comment: With @Bean annotation? I tried this, doesn't work. ObjectMapper object is probably created independently by MappingJackson2JsonView and Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.